# How to download all files from a webpage and find where HTTP requests are being made in the code?

Tags: javascript, http

I'm learning frontend development and browsing through websites trying to learn from what is on the web. One thing that escapes me is that when I work locally I just make a `fetch` request to `localhost:PORT/...` to my backend but I wanted to see what it looks like in production websites, e.g. finding where they make the request + server URL.

How would one download all files from a webpage and then find where an HTTP request is being made in the code?

In my mind it's searching for `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `axios` or something similar.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you want to download the website, so that you can use an editor to search for calls to fetch, xmlhttprequest, etc. But you don't need to download the files, to inspect their source code. Devtools exist for a reason, to make the life of both frontend and backend devs easier. Press `F12` or `CTRL+SHIFT+I` or right click and 'Inspect Element'. Then click the sources tab, and find the main response/file. Use `CTRL+F` to find strings like `fetch`, or JQuery `get` calls or Axios calls.

Comment: @GianSinghSarao Thank you! Is there a way to search across all files? I couldn't find the functionality, otherwise I'd be clicking through lots of JS files

Comment: Different web applications use different frameworks, and there will be varying levels of difficulty in understanding the code you download, depending on things like whether they're minimizing and/or obfuscating their javascript, or even using compiled WebAssembly. For simple web pages, you can just open up dev tools to see the javascript that the browser has loaded and look through it. There's not going to be any good programmatic way to do what you're asking. And you'll probably learn more by looking at tutorials than you will by trying to reverse-engineer random websites.

Comment: "search across all files?": Ctrl-Shift-F